# Choice of SMTP server to send e-mail to myself from Python for logging purposes

Tags: python, email, logging, smtp

The Python logging library provides a class called "SMTPHandler" that will let me e-mail myself the outputs of logging commands. I've some pasted below some example code I found on [a (possibly old) website for the library](http://www.red-dove.com/python_logging.html). I can modify it to get it to work with either gmail or my ISP as the SMTP server, but both cases require my password. I currently know of two possible solutions:

1. I can hardcode my password, which I'd prefer not to do, since this code finds its way onto a cloud revision control server.
2. I can file my password away in a text file on my machine and have my code read it, which seems ugly. With a [more effort](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring/) I may be able to store the password encrypted, rather than as plaintext.

I'm using a Mac, and I can e-mail myself by running `mail` on the command line and get the e-mail just fine. I don't know what `mail` is doing but it may be able to get my SMTP server details from the same place that Mac Mail reads them from and then use the external SMTP server. I tried setting MAILHOST="localhost" in the Python code below and that didn't work.

Is there a better way than #1 or #2 to get these e-mails to my gmail address?

```
import logging, logging.handlers

MAILHOST = 'beta'
FROM     = 'log_test5@yourdomain.com'
TO       = ['arkadi_renko']
SUBJECT  = 'Test Logging email from Python logging module (non-buffering)'

def main():
    log = logging.getLogger("")
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    hdlr = logging.handlers.SMTPHandler(MAILHOST, FROM, TO, SUBJECT)
    hdlr.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(levelname)-5s %(message)s"))
    log.addHandler(hdlr)
    log.info("Test email contents")
    log.removeHandler(hdlr)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to do the exact same thing. You can give [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html) a try. Something like

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

msg = MIMEText('YOUR_MESSAGE_BODY')
me = 'YOUR_SOURCE@EMAIL.COM'
you = 'YOUR_TARGET@EMAIL.COM'
msg['Subject'] = 'YOUR_MESSAGE_SUBJECT'
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail(me, [you], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

No password is involved.

If you encounter errors like

```
...    
error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

It probably means you don't have smtp server installed or enabled on your mac, installing `postfix` (say from macports) should fix that.

Comment: Works! Note to others, though: these e-mails go right to my gmail spam folder.